# printf type specifier

Tags: php, types, printf

I now want to know that means this line:

printf("Answer: %00010.6f", 22);

He prints: 022.000000. But way? i know whar 6f means float.

thansk for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this format string means:

- use 0 as filling character
- fill to a minimum of 3 characters before the . ( 2 -> 002, 23 -> 023, longer numbers stay as they are)
- display exactly 10 characters (including the delimiter)
- use . as decimal delimiter
- display 6 digits after the delimiter
- type float

Comment: The width specifier (10 in this case) is not a minimum but the actual width.  
    printf("%00010.6f\n", 22.1234567891234);  
displays  
    022.123457

Answer (score 2):

After initially thinking this was C (result of long habit), I realize this is for PHP.  Mostly the same, but the constant seems to be handled differently.

Anyway, the parameters in your code break down as follows:

- f = print the number as a floating point
- 10 = total field width of ten digits
- 000 = print up to 3 leading zeros when applicable (i.e. if there aren't 3 significant figures left of the decimal point)
- . = use a dot as the decimal separator
- 6 = six places after the decimal

It seems the printing parameters for PHP's printf are actually on the [sprintf page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).

Answer (score 1):

The `printf()` syntax and meanings are very well-documented.  Look at the [printf(3) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) or the [Wikipedia printf entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf#printf_format_placeholders).

The particular example you gave means: print a floating point number. Give it 6 characters after the decimal point.  Then prefix it with zeros until it is at least 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

printf("Answer: %f", 22) would enter the number 22 to the string "Answer: %f" in the place of the "%f" and print it as a float ("f" is for "float").
The numbers between the "%" and the "f" are to set the format - the number of digits that the printout will have.